# VSIX logo not showing for VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX). I have an old project targeting Visual Studio 2019, and a new project targeting Visual Studio 2022, for the same extension. They both have the same .png file in the same place in the folder structure, a subfolder called "Images" where the image is located. They both use it as the logo/icon.

They both have a source.extension.vsixmanifest file with the following tag:

```
<Metadata>
  ...
  <Icon>Images\VsExtension.png</Icon>
</Metadata>
```

Both of them target Community, Pro and Enterprise.

When I compile and debug the VSIX2019 project from VS2022 to a VS2019 or VS2022 instance, it is installed properly, and when I go to Extensions -> Manage extensions -> Installed, I see my extension installed with the VsExtension.png image as a logo.

When I compile and debug the VSIX2022 project from VS2022 to a VS2022 instance, it is installed properly, and when I go to Extensions -> Manage extensions -> Installed, I see my extension installed but with no logo.

None of them are published to Marketplace.

Does a VSIX project targeted for 2022 require something more than one targeted for 2019 in order to load and present a logo from a .png file?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, restarting Visual Studio 2022 (the one I'm developing the extensions in, not the one I'm debugging) helped.